# Java chess table

Tags: java, swing, colors, paintcomponent, jcomponent

I would like to apologise in advance for writing this code in Estonian, not in English.
I am beginner in Java(2-3hour experience so far). I am trying to write code for customizable chess table.(size customizable)So far I have been able to write code for the table but I have problem with coloring it. How do I color table according to the right colors of chess table ?
    package esimene;

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Joonistame4 extends JComponent implements ActionListener{

int suurus = 10;
int korgus = 10;
int x = 50;
int y = 50;
JTextField tf = new JTextField(String.valueOf(suurus));
JTextField tf2 = new JTextField(String.valueOf(korgus));
JColorChooser varvivalik = new JColorChooser();
JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2)); //rida , veerg
JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox();


public Joonistame4(){
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(new Label("suurus: "));
    p.add(tf);

    add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    //add(varvivalik, BorderLayout.EAST);
    tf.addActionListener(this);
    cb.addActionListener(this);
    varvivalik.setPreviewPanel(new JPanel());
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    int suurus_kokku = 8*suurus;
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    for(int x = suurus; x < suurus_kokku; x = x+suurus) {

        for(int y = suurus; y < suurus_kokku; y = y+suurus) {
            if(cb.isSelected()){
                g.fillRect(50, 50, suurus, suurus);
            }else{
                g.drawRect(50+y, 50+x, suurus, suurus);
                }       
            }

    }
}   



public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame aken = new JFrame("Esimene aken");
    aken.setSize(600, 600);
    aken.getContentPane().add(new Joonistame4());
    aken.setVisible(true);
    aken.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    suurus = Integer.parseInt(tf.getText());
    repaint();

}

}
```

Comment: Please post relevant parts only.

Comment: name variables english please

Comment: You can use `setColor` multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me tell you that this is a somewhat odd approach to creating a chessboard in Java. But that also depends on your goal - I guess for educational reasons you should continue :)

To use the `Java Graphics` to draw with different colors you have to use the `g.setColor(SOME_COLOR);` in front of each `g.fillRect(...)` or `g.drawRect(...)` or any other painting function. Those functions always paint with the "currently set" color.

Comment: Yes this is on educational purposes.Thank you this partly answered my question. Only question would be how do I swap between white and black as it is in chess board ?

Comment: @ArmidoMaamägi if he answered your question, then please do so and accept his answer

Answer (score 3):

If the problem is actually determining which color to paint a cell, the easiest way is to look at whether the two numbers added together is an odd number or an even number and paint the cell accordingly.

i.e. for each cell

```
boolean blackSquare = (x+y)%2==0;
```

If `blackSquare` is set then paint the cell one colour, if not then paint it the other.

To actually set the colour, just make the appropriate call before painting the square.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. I have used this in python but didnt know how to use it in java.